# dúvida sobre aninhamento de listas

Tags: python, lista

sou novo por aqui e na programação, estou no momento aprendendo conceitos de listas (ainda não aprendi Bibliotecas. Já que estou seguindo videoaulas do youtube.).
Enquanto estava estudando sobre, eu tive uma ideia divertida para aprimorar minhas habilidades em listas.
1 - Criar Tabela do Brasileirão
2 - Utilizando o modulo random (choice, randint) para sortear um time dentro da lista e criar um placar.
3 - Verificar qual foi o vencendo pelo placar
4 - Alterar a tabela de acordo com as informações (Onde travei e não conseguir avançar)

```
from random import randint, choice
times = [['Palmeiras', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ['Internacional', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ['Corinthians', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         ['Flamengo', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ['Fluminense', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ['Athletico-PR', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         ['Atlético-MG', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ['América-MG', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],['Botafogo', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         ['Fortaleza', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ['Santos', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ['São Paulo', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         ['Bragantino', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ['Goiás', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ['Coritiba', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         ['Ceará SC', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ['Cuiabá', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ['Atlético-GO', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         ['Avaí', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ['Juventude', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]


clube1 = choice(times)
clube2 = choice(times)
gol1 = randint(0, 3)
gol2 = randint(0, 3)

print(f'{clube1[0]} {gol1} x {gol2} {clube2[0]}')
if gol1 > gol2:
    print(f'{clube1[0]} Venceu.')
elif gol1 == gol2:
    print('EMPATE')
else:
    print(f'{clube2[0]} Venceu.')

print()
print(f'{"Clubes":<30}{"Pts":<5}{"PJ":<4}{"VIT":<6}{"E":<4}{"DER":<6}{"SG"}')
for tabela in times:
    if tabela in times[0:4]:
        print(f'\033[34m{tabela[0]:<30}\033[m{tabela[1]:>1}{tabela[2]:>5}{tabela[3]:>5}{tabela[4]:>5}{tabela[5]:>5}{tabela[6]:>5}')
    elif tabela in times[4:6]:
        print(f'\033[33m{tabela[0]:<30}\033[m{tabela[1]:>1}{tabela[2]:>5}{tabela[3]:>5}{tabela[4]:>5}{tabela[5]:>5}{tabela[6]:>5}')
    elif tabela in times[6:12]:
        print(f'\033[32m{tabela[0]:<30}\033[m{tabela[1]:>1}{tabela[2]:>5}{tabela[3]:>5}{tabela[4]:>5}{tabela[5]:>5}{tabela[6]:>5}')
    elif tabela in times[12:16]:
        print(f'{tabela[0]:<30}{tabela[1]:>1}{tabela[2]:>5}{tabela[3]:>5}{tabela[4]:>5}{tabela[5]:>5}{tabela[6]:>5}')
    else:
        print(f'\033[31m{tabela[0]:<30}\033[m{tabela[1]:>1}{tabela[2]:>5}{tabela[3]:>5}{tabela[4]:>5}{tabela[5]:>5}{tabela[6]:>5}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Basta selecionar o índice da pontuação que quer alterar e incrementar o valor.

```
if gol1 > gol2:
    print(f'{clube1[0]} Venceu.')
    clube1[1] += 3
elif gol1 == gol2:
    print('EMPATE')
    clube1[1] += 1
    clube2[1] += 1
else:
    print(f'{clube2[0]} Venceu.')
    clube2[1] += 3
```